# How can I turn off the new keyring pop-up window?

Tags: release-loki, google-chrome, elementary-website, keyring

Everytime I open Chrome a window pops-up (see below) and asks me to set up a new keyring. I did a quick research and learned that it might happen because user login is disabled on start. I switched that on but still got the same pop-up. How can I remove/turn off/disable it?

[image]

Comment: I followed the instructions found here -
http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/676/how-to-change-or-remove-keyrings-on-elementary-os

Option #1 - installing seahorse
- I unlocked the default keyring in Passwords & Keys but it did not solve my problem, it kept popping up. Then I deleted it which did not help either.

Option #2 - command line (rm ~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring
)
- got this answer in terminal
rm: cannot remove '/home/name/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring': No such file or directory

What else should I try now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay! After some heavy digging,

1. First, update Chrome (`⋮ in upper-right corner > Help > About Google Chrome`)—a fix has already been submitted but it did not fix all issues. Then subscribe to [the bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=643189) and report your issue so the devs know they can ask for your help testing a potential fix.
2. If the update doesn't fix it, try running Chrome with the `--password-store=basic` flag: 
   `google-chrome-stable --password-store=basic`
   If you want to set your Chrome icon to run this command, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117341/how-can-i-find-desktop-files).

If that doesn't work, you're looking at playing around with your keyrings, which are in `~/.local/share/keyrings`. But I'd sooner recommend that you follow the latest alternative advice in the [the bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=643189).

Comment: Hi wolf!Thank you for doing some research!

Comment: Hi wolf!

Thank you for doing some research!

I have the same issue when open Opera, my default browser but do not have it with any other browsers.

I've tried all that you posted above.
1. chrome is up to date
2. it works well - no keyring pop-up
3. mv: cannot stat '/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon': No such file or directory

Basically, it is still theere when I open Opera/Chrome.

Comment: So it looks like `--password-store=basic` is the fix for now. If you want to update your shortcut, you can add that flag to [its .desktop file](http://askubuntu.com/q/117341/49899)

Comment: The annoying pop-up has just disappeared (after restarting my computer several times). I suppose option #2 fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's the GNOME keyring as it's probably based in it, and if it's in the startup applications.

Also, have you tried to really make the keyring? It's improved security, and it will keep your logins in the keyring.